# Group by over columns with same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and i want to categorize them if they fall in a specific time period

What i have now:

```
SELECT RelatieId,
   AccountId,
   [UaId],
   [VisitDate],
   [Titel],
   [Editie],
   CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, v.LastVisit, v.VisitDate) > (10 * 60)
       THEN 0
       ELSE 1
   END AS reset
   FROM rfv.click v
```

This results is something like this

```html
RelatieId   AccountId   UaId    VisitDate   Titel   reset
70409280    120211  8408    2019-04-01 09:15:52.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:45:41.000 Nx  0
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:45:55.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:46:10.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:47:16.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:52:52.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:53:14.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 12:02:44.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 12:03:08.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:06:42.000 Nx  0
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:07:07.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:36:15.000 Nx  0
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:36:26.000 Nx  1
```

but what i actually need is

```html
RelatieId   AccountId   UaId    VisitDate   Titel   needed 
70409280    120211  8408    2019-04-01 09:15:52.000 Nx  1
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:45:41.000 Nx  2
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:45:55.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:46:10.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:47:16.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:52:52.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 11:53:14.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 12:02:44.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-01 12:03:08.000 Nx  3
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:06:42.000 Nx  4
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:07:07.000 Nx  5
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:36:15.000 Nx  6
70409280    120211  14531   2019-04-02 08:36:26.000 Nx  7
```

Comment: Its sql 2017 @jarlh

Comment: What is the length of the time period that you want to group the row by?

Comment: I don't understand the results.  Why would the second row not have the same value as the third row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure when you want this to reset (start over at 1), for example for a different RelatieId, or for a different AccountId, or for both. You'd need to adjust the `PARTITION BY` of both `LAG` and `SUM` window functions. Here's a basic version:

```
;WITH resetChangeCTE AS
(
    SELECT *
         , IIF(reset != LAG(reset, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY RelatieId, AccountId ORDER BY VisitDate), 1, 0) AS hasResetChanged
     FROM (VALUES (70409280,    120211,  8408 ,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 09:15:52.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 11:45:41.000'), 0),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 11:45:55.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 11:46:10.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 11:47:16.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 11:52:52.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 11:53:14.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 12:02:44.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-01 12:03:08.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-02 08:06:42.000'), 0),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-02 08:07:07.000'), 1),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-02 08:36:15.000'), 0),
                  (70409280,    120211,  14531,   CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-04-02 08:36:26.000'), 1)) x(RelatieId  , AccountId   , UaId    ,VisitDate   ,reset)
)
SELECT *, SUM(hasResetChanged) OVER (PARTITION BY RelatieId, AccountId ORDER BY VisitDate) AS needed 
  FROM resetChangeCTE
```

So I'm first checking whether or not the `reset` value changes between current record and the previous one (using `LAG`, ordered by the visit date), and then summing the amount of changes up from the first record up until the current one using `SUM`. These are [window functions](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-window-functions-sql-server/), very useful.

[sqlfiddle with the result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/40605).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you really want:

```
SELECT c.*,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(SECOND, v.LastVisit, v.VisitDate) > (10 * 60)
                THEN 0
                ELSE 1
           END) AS needed
FROM (SELECT c.*,
             LAG(VisitDate) OVER (PARTITION BY RelatieId, AccountId, UaId ORDER BY VisitDate) as LastVisit
      FROM rfv.click c
     ) c;
```

This doesn't return exactly the results you specify.  However, this seems more useful and may be what you really intend.